# Load a page into an iframe with C# ASP.NET, Razor, and MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to load an external page (i.e. google or facebook auth) into a iframe when the user clicks a button. How would you do this using MVC3 and Razor?

This seems like an extremely trivial task, but I can’t seem to figure out what to ask Google so I get something back I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use JQuery something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myButton').click(function () {
            $('#myFrame').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com/');
        });
    });
</script>
<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
<button id="myButton">
    Refresh IFrame
</button>
```

However, you will find that some sites (such as google.com) will prevent you from doing this, as they can specify in their response header whether or not the page can be opened in an IFrame.  This is to prevent ['clickjacking'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) and is built in to most modern browsers.